# Update profile not working with TYPO3 V 8.7.7 and sr_feuser_registration v 5.0.0

Tags: typo3-8.7.x, sr-feuser-registration

I have used TYPO3 8 Latest version with repository extension sr_feuser_registration(5.0.0) and my systems using php version 7.1.99.

Edit User profile is not working. when i click on update profile button it's just refresh the page not update profile. Also i debug the code and i get always `isSubmit` value `false`. but when i enable `editPreview` then update profile working fine.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are several related bugs posted on [forge.typo3.org](https://forge.typo3.org/projects/extension-sr_feuser_register/issues?set_filter=1&tracker_id=1).

Alternatively you can try [femanager](https://github.com/einpraegsam/femanager).